# Check If table partition exists for date

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have created a partition function on a table: `BIZ_DATE_TRADE_PF()`.

The column I specify to create the function is a business date for example: `20220616`.

I have a java application, that needs to check existence of this partition for a given business date before executing the ALTER statement that modifies the partition using the current business date:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION BIZ_DATE_TRADE_PF() SPLIT RANGE (:bizDate)
```

I can check for the existence of this partition by name by querying `SELECT * FROM SYS.partition_functions` but how do I check current partition exists for the given business date, already created or not?

Comment: Partitions already exist for all possible dates. Is your intent to partition by a fixed period (e.g. day/month/year) and create boundaries dynamically such that all data for a given period is in the same partition and partitions exist for every period between the min/max date? I suggest you pre-create partitions via a maintenance job instead of on demand because splitting a non-empty partition is very expensive due to data movement and requires 4x logging of normal DML.

Comment: `sys.partition_range_values` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, $PARTITION.BIZ_DATE_TRADE_PF('20220616') AS "PARTITION"
FROM   ??? AS f --> the partitionned table
)
SELECT T.*, fs.name AS FILEGROUP_NAME,
            f.name AS FILE_NAME,
            f.physical_name
FROM   T
       JOIN sys.partitions AS p
            ON   p.object_id = OBJECT_ID('???') --> the partitionned table
            AND  T."PARTITION" = p.partition_number
            AND  index_id = 0
       JOIN sys.allocation_units AS au
            ON p.hobt_id = au.container_id
       JOIN sys.filegroups AS fs
            ON au.data_space_id = fs.data_space_id
       JOIN sys.database_files AS f
            ON fs.data_space_id = f.file_id;
```